# How to group ID in while loop (for php json_encode)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, loops

I have a problem for several days to create a Json array with MySQL data

Here are my MySQL data:

```
zi  zn         vn                       pioo     pio     ve    station    es       eo  

 1  Zone 1     Value 01                  1     199       0        1       1         0
 1  Zone 1     Value 02                 54     637       0        3       0         0
 1  Zone 1     Value 03                 55     637       1        3       0         0
 2  Zone 2     Value 01                  1     199       0        1       1         0
 2  Zone 2     Value 03                 55     637       1        3       0         0
 2  Zone 2     Value 04                 56     642       0        3       0         0
 3  Zone 3     Value 01                  1     199       0        1       1         0
 3  Zone 3     Value 05                 57     647       1        3       0         0
 4  Zone 4     Value 05                 57     647       1        3       0         0
 5  Zone Test  Value 02                 54     637       0        3       0         0
 5  Zone Test  Value 03                 55     637       1        3       0         0
```

Here is my PHP code:

My query is $query and my SQL connexion is $con

```
$result = array();
$json_response = array();
$response = array();


if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($zoneId,$zoneName,$vanneName,$piooId,$pioId,$vanne_etat,$station,$etat_station,$etat_ordre);

    while($stmt->fetch()){


            $json_response = [
                    'zi' => $zoneId,
                'zn' => $zoneName,
                $vanneName => [],
            ];

        $json_response[$vanneName][] = [
            'pioo' => $piooId,
            'pio' => $pioId,
            've' => $vanne_etat,
            'es' => $etat_station,
            'eo' => $etat_ordre,
        ];



    $data = [];
    foreach ($json_response as $element) {
        $data[] = $element;
    }

        $result[]=$json_response;


    }
    $stmt->close();


    $online = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS online FROM relevés_instantanés ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")) ['online'];
    $response["online"] = $online;
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["data"] = $result;


}else{
    //Errors
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_error($con);


}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Output Json like that :

```
{
   "online":"1",
   "success":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "zi":1,
         "zn":"Zone 1",
         "Value 01":[
            {
               "pioo":1,
               "pio":199,
               "ve":0,
               "es":1,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":1,
         "zn":"Zone 1",
         "Value 02":[
            {
               "pioo":54,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":0,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":1,
         "zn":"Zone 1",
         "Value 03":[
            {
               "pioo":55,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":2,
         "zn":"Zone 2",
         "Value 01":[
            {
               "pioo":1,
               "pio":199,
               "ve":0,
               "es":1,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":2,
         "zn":"Zone 2",
         "Value 03":[
            {
               "pioo":55,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":2,
         "zn":"Zone 2",
         "Value 04":[
            {
               "pioo":56,
               "pio":642,
               "ve":0,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":3,
         "zn":"Zone 3",
         "Value 01":[
            {
               "pioo":1,
               "pio":199,
               "ve":0,
               "es":1,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":3,
         "zn":"Zone 3",
         "Value 05":[
            {
               "pioo":57,
               "pio":647,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":4,
         "zn":"Zone 4",
         "Value 05":[
            {
               "pioo":57,
               "pio":642,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":5,
         "zn":"Zone Test",
         "Value 02":[
            {
               "pioo":54,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":0,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":5,
         "zn":"Zone Test",
         "Value 03":[
            {
               "pioo":55,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But I expect an ouput like that : (I am not sure of the syntax, but it is for you to understand my wish.)

```
{
   "online":"1",
   "success":1,
   "data":[
      {

         "zi":1,
         "zn":"Zone 1"{
         "Value 01":[
                {
                   "pioo":1,
                   "pio":199,
                   "ve":0,
                   "es":1,
                   "eo":0
                }
             ]
             "Value 02":[
                {
                   "pioo":54,
                   "pio":637,
                   "ve":0,
                   "es":0,
                   "eo":0
                }
             ]
             "Value 03":[
                {
                   "pioo":55,
                   "pio":637,
                   "ve":1,
                   "es":0,
                   "eo":0
                }
             ]
          },


      {
         "zi":2,
         "zn":"Zone 2"{
         "Value 01":[
            {
               "pioo":1,
               "pio":199,
               "ve":0,
               "es":1,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
         "Value 03":[
            {
               "pioo":55,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]

         "Value 04":[
            {
               "pioo":56,
               "pio":642,
               "ve":0,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },

      {
         "zi":3,
         "zn":"Zone 3"{
         "Value 01":[
            {
               "pioo":1,
               "pio":199,
               "ve":0,
               "es":1,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
         "Value 05":[
            {
               "pioo":57,
               "pio":647,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },


      {
         "zi":4,
         "zn":"Zone 4"{
         "Value 05":[
            {
               "pioo":57,
               "pio":642,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      },


      {
         "zi":5,
         "zn":"Zone Test"{
         "Value 02":[
            {
               "pioo":54,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":0,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
         "Value 03":[
            {
               "pioo":55,
               "pio":637,
               "ve":1,
               "es":0,
               "eo":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can not isolate each id of Zones to correctly build my JSON ....

Is it possible to use each ID once in the while loop?

any help appreciated

Sorry for my bad english .. :S

Joel

Comment: Your using `mysqli`  not `PDO` right?  Just from glancing at it, it's pretty messy.  There is a lot of variable confusion going on.  Like this loop `foreach ($json_response as $element)` is just confusing the issue.  your resetting this variable `$json_response = [ ... ]` on every loop itteration, not sure if that is intended.

Comment: The format you want it in, looks to be invalid, here specifically `"zn":"Zone 1"{`  Maybe just a typo, but is it nested in that element?

Comment: Yes I'm using mysqli. I know it's messy... I'm trying for several days.... whitout any succes... I'm a little lost ... hence my call for help ...

Comment: It's all good, you provided quite a bit of info. I just need to sort though it so I can figure out what you want.  Probably we will have to do 2 loops.  If it was `PDO` we could do `FETCH_GROUP` and group the results on the `Zone`.  That would make it easier.

Comment: to try to be clearer: I would like to isolate each 'zi' with its name ('zn') and inside the corresponding data. (Value xx, pioo, pio etc. ..). I do not know PDO well because I've never used it ... I'm normally comfortable with mysqli

Comment: It's harder when its done with `bind_result`, if you could give me a flat assoc array of the data right from the database, I could structure it in a few minutes.  If you do that, print it with `var_export` not `print_r`, it's just too complex to do without the data. (ie do in my head)

Comment: I would do it `{"data" : { "zone_1" : [{...},{...}], "zone_2" : [{}] }}` programmatically you can split `zone_{n}` for the ids, and the name formatting.  This would let you do  `data['zone_{n}'][] = $row` etc.

Comment: Yes I see, But I don't know the name "zn" will have. "Zone" is for exemple, but I may be called something else... The important for me is to isolate each ID "zi" with it's associated name "zn". I'm changing the code with mysqli_fetch_array. I post it asap

Comment: Here is the modified code : 

`
$requete = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($requete))
{
   

          $json_response = [
            'zi' => $rows['zi'],
              'zn' => $rows['zn'],
              $rows['vn'] => [],
          ];

      $json_response[$rows['vn']][] = [
          'pioo' => $rows['pioo'],
          'pio' => $rows['pio'],
          've' => $rows['ve'],
          'es' => $rows['es'],
          'eo' => $rows['eo'],
      ];

.....
`

Comment: The code doesn't matter, its the data that I need as I'm not going to build a DB table for this. Doesn't matter I made a small array from the data you put already.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood what you needed :S

Comment: Sorry, it only took me 30min to do it which includes formatting the answer, let me know if that format is acceptable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I would do it.  It's a slightly different structure but one that makes it easier to build.

Also I am not using a database so I will be using this canned array

```
 $a = [
    [
        "zi"        => "1",
        "zn"        => "Zone 1",
        "vn"        => "Value 01",
        "pioo"      => "1",
        "pio"       => "199",
        "ve"        => "0",
        "station"   => "1",
        "es"        => "1",
        "eo"        => "0"
    ],  [
        "zi"        => "1",
        "zn"        => "Zone 1",
        "vn"        => "Value 02",
        "pioo"      => "54",
        "pio"       => "637",
        "ve"        => "0",
        "station"   => "3",
        "es"        => "0",
        "eo"        => "0"
    ],[
        "zi"        => "2",
        "zn"        => "Zone 2",
        "vn"        => "Value 04",
        "pioo"      => "56",
        "pio"       => "642",
        "ve"        => "0",
        "station"   => "3",
        "es"        => "0",
        "eo"        => "0"
    ]
 ];
```

Where I have `foreach` below you can replace with your `while` loop from the database as long as the data is in `$data` per row, it should be fine.

```
  $output = [
      "online" => 0,
      "success" => 0,
      "data" => []
   ];

 foreach($a as $data){ 
   //replace foreach with while from the DB
   //eg. while(false != ($data = $stmt->fetch_assoc())){


    $zone = "zone_{$data['zi']}";
    if(!isset($output['data'][$zone])){
        //setup the zone first time we see it
        $output['data'][$zone] = [
            "zi" => $data['zi'],
            "zn" => $data['zn'],
        ];
    }
    
    $value = $data['vn'];
    
    if(!isset($output['data'][$zone][$value])) $output['data'][$zone][$value] = [];

    //remove these we don't want them anymore
    unset($data['zi'], $data['zn'], $data['vn']);
    
    $output['data'][$zone][$value][] = $data;
     
 }
 $output["online"] = 1;
 $output["success"] = 1;
```

You can test it online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d29258e0946e7826108e2154364ed4568c48c50e)

Output

```
 {
    "online": 1,
    "success": 1,
    "data": {
        "zone_1": {
            "zi": "1",
            "zn": "Zone 1",
            "Value 01": [
                {
                    "pioo": "1",
                    "pio": "199",
                    "ve": "0",
                    "station": "1",
                    "es": "1",
                    "eo": "0"
                }
            ],
            "Value 02": [
                {
                    "pioo": "54",
                    "pio": "637",
                    "ve": "0",
                    "station": "3",
                    "es": "0",
                    "eo": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        "zone_2": {
            "zi": "2",
            "zn": "Zone 2",
            "Value 04": [
                {
                    "pioo": "56",
                    "pio": "642",
                    "ve": "0",
                    "station": "3",
                    "es": "0",
                    "eo": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty close to the format you wanted but by adding this `$zone = "zone_{$data['zi']}";` in we can keep track of things a whole bunch nicer.

```
//php
$output['data'][$zone];

//json
"data": {
    "zone_1"
```

Otherwise we would have to group them by zone first, then in a second loop we could write them out.  As you said `I can not isolate each id of Zones to correctly build my JSON`  The way to solve that is to output the data to an array grouped by zone id, then loop though that. So we would have to build what I have above as stage 1, and then once they are grouped properly remove the `zone` key essentially.

As I mentioned in the comments there is an error in the format you want at the end of all this.  It's right here

```
"zn":"Zone 1"{   //<--- this bracket
     "Value 01":[
            {
    ...
```

So I don't know if that is just a typo, or if that was supposed to be part of the structure somehow (I just ignored it).

### UPDATE

It just occurred to me an easy way to remove the `$zone` key I added in. You can simply use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to strip the key out.  So somwthing like below, add that line just before encoding it as JSON.

```
 $output['data'] = array_values($output['data']);
```

This will change the structure to

```
 {
    "online": 1,
    "success": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "zi": "1",
            "zn": "Zone 1",
            "Value 01": [
                {
                    "pioo": "1",
                    "pio": "199",
                    "ve": "0",
                    "station": "1",
                    "es": "1",
                    "eo": "0"
                }
            ],
            "Value 02": [
                {
                    "pioo": "54",
                    "pio": "637",
                    "ve": "0",
                    "station": "3",
                    "es": "0",
                    "eo": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]   
}
```

You can see that online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a88328fc32b5c3e9736e2a1c1fc72cd102d0470) But because we backed in the structure before hand we get the advantage of indentifing they by the key (the $zon var)

Comment: It works perfectly !!! Thank you very much !! By dint of searching .... I got lost in something too complicated .... Your code is perfect for my needs. Thank you 1000x!

Comment: And it's only like 15 - 20 lines.  I like these kind of questions it's like a puzzle for me. ha ha.

Comment: You seem to know PHP well. Thank you very much for sharing your experience! I am not very comfortable with the arrays. I still have to practice a few years ... :-)

Comment: I only been doing PHP for 10 years, 8 years professionally.  Time flies.  That's why I try to explain how it works, so hopefully it makes more sense.  the array keys are unique, so you can use them for all kinds of shortcuts.

Comment: Ok, I understand better :-) It's good to have people like you on the Internet to help beginners !!

Comment: My work is not finished yet ... I must now treat this JSON array in an Android application (Java) The fun is just beginning haha. It will be for tomorrow. Time to sleep!

Comment: Java stinks... I used to do more Java, then I decided I didn't like it.  I actually had a class on Java (never had one on PHP)

Comment: I also had a class in Java, only for the purpose of developing a "professional" Android application as part of my job. I prefer PHP too. This JSON array will be used to transfer information between a MySQL database and my application. It may not be the best solution, but it meets my needs.